# Scikitlearn RandomForest excessive RAM usage

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I'm training a [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) on a 1.3 GB dataset. The data has few columns (< 10), and there are around 30 million entries. I'm not able to fit the model since I run out of memory (32GB) midway during the model training.

I read [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/datasciencebowl/forums/t/12520/scikit-learn-random-forest-memory-problem/99825) that the memory usage of `RandomForestClassifier` should be proportional to `2*n_jobs*size(X)`, which in my case is around 2GB, since I've restricted n_jobs to 1. However, this code is eating up all 32 GBs on my remote instance, which does not add up. Would appreciate help in figuring this out.

I'm running Python 2.7.6 with scikit-learn 0.17. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

def run():
    print 'Loading DataFrame'
    df_train = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv')

    print 'Splitting train and test data'
    train, test = train_test_split(df_train, test_size=0.2)

    del df_train

    df = train
    features = ['x', 'y', 'accuracy', 'hour', 'day', 'week', 'month', 'year']

    df.loc[:, 'hours'] = df.time / float(60)
    df.loc[:, 'hour'] = df.hours % 24

    df.loc[:, 'days'] = df.time / float(60*24)
    df.loc[:, 'day'] = df.days % 7

    df.loc[:, 'weeks'] = df.time / float(60*24*7)
    df.loc[:, 'week'] = df.weeks % 52

    df.loc[:, 'months'] = df.time / float(60*24*30)
    df.loc[:, 'month'] = df.months % 12

    df.loc[:, 'year'] = df.time / float(60*24*365)

    model = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=1, warm_start=True)

    train_df = df.loc[:, features]
    values = df.loc[:, 'val']

    print 'Fitting Model'
    model.fit(train_df, values)

    wdf = test.sort_values('row_id').set_index('row_id')        
    expected = wdf.place_id
    wdf = wdf.loc[:, features]

    predictions = model.predict(wdf)
    actual = predictions
    print dict(zip(wdf.index, predictions))

    expect = pd.Series(expected)
    actual = pd.Series(actual)
    print (sum(expect == actual)/float(len(expected))) * 100
```

Comment: First, did you try to reduce the number of parallel jobs and see if it helps? second, don't you have some garbage collection that you could do (by setting some unneeded variables to None before the end of `run()`  and possibly call `gc.collect()` ?)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I've set `n_jobs=1` and it helps, albeit marginally. The only time this code runs to completion is if I set `n_estimators=3`, which in turn leads to abysmal predictions! Will try `gc.collect()`